# Repeated long command in gnome-terminal do not show up in full

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Let's say I type a shell command in gnome-terminal/bash that spans multiple lines and run it.

```
shell> abcdef ghijk lmn
opq rstuv wxyz
```

Then when I want to run the same command again, I hit the up-arrow. Instead of seeing the same command again (which always used to be the case), gnome-terminal now only shows me parts of the last line with a `<` at the beginning of the line:

```
<stuv wxyz
```

That is, no prompt, just that line.

If I hit <kbd>CTRL-A</kbd> at that point, I will get the first line of the original command with a `>` at the end.

```
shell> abcdef ghijk l>
```

Here, the prompt is back.

How can I configure my setup so that hitting the up-arrow after a long command will simply display the complete long command again, spanning multiple lines and including the prompt?

Comment: This do not seems the default behavior. Can you please tell if the terminal profile has been changed, what shell are you using, if you modified `~/.bashrc`, if you are using `screen` or every other possibly interesting information.

Comment: I actually found out right after posting this that I screwed up my TERM variable, but I do not have enough points to answer my own question yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your TERM variable is set correctly, i.e. reflecting the type of terminal you are on. Typically, you would export the TERM variable in your ~/.bashrc file, as outlined by Justin Andrusk's answer:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

In the case of the question, I had played with a complex command to extract search terms from a file, and I used a variable named TERM for the search terms, without realizing the  significance of that variable name.

Comment: this is why you should use lowercase variable names

Answer (score 1):

Modify your XTERM variable to 'xterm' in ~/.bashrc with:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

:)